# Event equivalent to controller_front_init_before from magento 1 in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.2

I'm using `controller_front_init_before` in Magento1.But I want to use the same event in magento2.

Which event is equal to this `event name`? If anyone knows please explain me...

Answer (score 1):

Try this event for call before any controller action

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
```

Comment: This event not working  when I'm loading category page second time ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before` plugin on `\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController::dispatch` instead of event

Related docs - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html